# Randomise numeric values in certain position in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring

I have an NVCHAR(30) column in a table that I need randomise the numeric values with a particular start and end position and the column contains numeric values of different format.

**Sample**
Value type 1

```
337-27636993-219322
```

Value type 2

```
01121041303803168640
```

For box types, I need randomise the values starting from position 5 and ending at positon 12, so with the examples provides the following digits is what I expect to randomise.

```
27636993
10413038
```

I know how to do a substring  to find the starting position and length but that only extracts out the values I want to randomize. What I need is the sql code to pick the set of values I need, randomize them and then do an update to the existing number.

So if the original number was  as follows;

```
337-27636993-219322
```

and the new number generated was;

```
56413037
```

The end result in the table would be;

```
337-56413037-219322
```

I'm confident with SQL but I am no guru, so all the help would be appreciated

Comment: Sorry, this must be my poor English showing but what do you mean by "For box types"? Does is stand for "For values of type 1"?

Comment: What are you doing this for?  Why do you only need to randomize the "middle" set of digits?  Why can't you randomize the whole thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use `stuff()` and a random number generator.  Something like this should work:

```
SELECT Stuff(col, 5, 8, RIGHT(Replicate('0', 8) 
                              + Cast(Cast(Rand(Checksum(Newid()))*100000000 AS 
                              INT) AS 
                                     VARCHAR(255)), 8))
```

The idea is simple.  `stuff()` will replace characters in a string, which is exactly what you want to do.  Generating the random number as a string is a bit of work.

- rand(checksum(newid())) generates a random number
- rand(checksum(newid())) * 100000000 creates an 8 digit number (with decimal points)
- then cast it to an integer (which is big enough to store this expression)
- then cast it to a string
- prepend it with `'0'`s, so if it has fewer than 8 characters they will be padded
- then use `right()` to get the 8-digit number

Comment: Thank you Gordon Linoff, your solution did exactly what I needed.